# Does the length of the selector affect the speed?

Tags: jquery

So in some cases for better code readability i use like `div#parent div.someclass a`, but also can do just like `div.someclass a`. So which version is better and faster?

Comment: An id selector is much faster than a class selector. If you use `div#parent div.someclass a`, it looks for `.someclass a` only inside #parent element. If you just use `div.someclass a`, it will search trough all the DOM tree, which makes it slower.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. Even if the only elements with `someclass` classes are inside `#parent`,  there is no practical difference in speed.

Comment: For better code readability don't put the tagname before the #. That is, use "#parent", not "div#parent". If you're selecting by ID you don't need the tagname, so when you _do_ include it that leaves anybody reading your code wondering whether you actually _intended_ "select the element with ID 'parent' only if it is a div".

Answer (score 1):

It's important when using JQuery to consider that the selectors have to be converted to native browser functions at the end of the day. This means that you should try to use Id or tag based selectors whenever possible. 
I recommend using `$("div#parent").find("div.someclass a")` for better performance

This gives better performance since it will use the optimized tag/id selector to get the parent, and the slower class based selector is applied to a much more limited set since it is only applied to the descendants of the specified parent.